# What's the python-friendly way to generate a value in a function only if one isn't passed to it?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I'm trying to filter a really big time series in chunks. I'm passing the chunks to a function butter_bandpass_filter (below). Every chunk needs an initial filter conditions array ([zi](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter_zi.html)), but the first chunk does not have a zi. I want this function to be able to generate one for the first chunk, and then notice that I'm passing it one for the rest of them, and not bother to calculate them.

Right now, this runs, but I get the error:

:12: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
if zi == "init":

presumably because after the first chunk, it's comparing the string i'm giving it in the arguments to the numpy array that gets passed to it thereafter. Is there a smarter way to do this that won't give this error?

This is my first SO post, so sorry in advance about the conventions that I've violated. :p

```
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter, lfilter_zi

def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
    return b, a

def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, zi="init", order=5):
    b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    if zi == "init":
        zi = lfilter_zi(b, a)
    return lfilter(b, a, data, zi=zi)
```

Comment: Instead of the string 'init' use `None` and a `if zi is None:` test.

Comment: Are you sure you're giving zi as a string when calling butter_bandpass_filter ? I feel like this error comes from python converting zi to string for the comparaison. 
Anyway @hpaulj is right, use  'zi=None' then compare 'if zi is not None'

Comment: @hpaulj fixed it! Thank you!